# Can't check CheckBoxCell in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have defined a CheckBoxCell in my DataGridView's columns, and the properties are as follows:[image]

But the problem is I can't seem to check the box. I can click it and all but the box never gets checked.

I add rows via the following code:

```
Dim row(3) As String
row(1) = "foo"
row(2) = "bar"

DataGridViewCustom.Rows.Add(row)
```

`row(0)` is the cell where the checkbox is located. I've tried using `row(0) = True` and `row(0) = False`, but it still doesn't allow me to check or uncheck the box during runtime.

I've already set `DataGridViewCustom.Enabled = True` and `DataGridViewCustom.ReadOnly = False` - in fact these are default variables that never change.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your read only to false, you have it set to true for that column.